# how to convert dx7 levels, rates, and global operator level to gain values and seconds for Web Audio oscillator gain nodes?

Tags: web-audio-api

It is hard to distill this and give enough detail but not too much.

I think I understand the basics of how to do frequency modulation (or maybe it's actually phase modulation) in Web Audio. Although I don't understand the feedback loop well or how to implement the 0 to 7 feedback strength setting.

Every operator / oscillator is has two lines setting the gain to make envelopes, as I loop through all oscillators:

`op_gain[j].gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
targetGain, times[j][k]);

op_gain[j].gain.setValueAtTime(
targetGain, times[j][k]);`

where targetGain has just been calculated for that oscillator at that time from an object containing dx7 parameters. The question is how to get from dx7 parameters to these gain and time values, whether for carriers, modulators, or modulators in a feedback loop. Every operator has a dx7 global level, four dx7 rates and four dx7 levels to shape the envelope, an additional value between 0 and 127 to determine how loud the note is (most notes are played by six oscillators), and a length in seconds that the note should last.

After much scouring online, three resources look the most relevant:

- mmontag's dx7 replica - https://github.com/mmontag/dx7-synth-js/tree/master/src - but the code is hard for someone with novice JavaScript skills to understand; it appears to set envelopes on a per sample level rather than using `.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime` or the like, and I'm not sure how to get it working solely on the client-side even offline
- https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/wiki/img/ - a couple html pages in here can give a clue to converting levels to dB and rates to dB/s (but no details on modifications to make for attack rates as opposed to decay and release rates) and what the envelope looks like given four levels and rates (but I need output values in seconds, not samples)
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/master/wiki/Dx7Envelope.wiki - probably the most promising, but written for not-quite-beginners...

This last resource gives some of the answers I need:

> Then, the total level is 64 `*` actual level + 32 `*` output level, normalized
> for full scale. This "total level" is in units of approx .0235 dB (20 log<sub>10</sub>(2) / 256), so that 256 of these steps doubles the amplitude.

Previously it explained how to get "actual level" from the four dx7 level numbers and "output level" from (I think) the dx7 global operator level.

But which value is normalized for full scale, and what needs to be added to the formula to do that normalizing? (Full scale is defined later: "Full scale means both L and output level set to 99 in the patch, and no additional scaling.") How do I convert a number in units of .0235 dB to dB so that I can convert dB to Web Audio gain (which I think I saw somewhere can be done by `Math.pow(10, (db / 20))`, but my understanding of dB is shaky)? And then presumably multiply that gain value by (the-0-to-127-note-velocity-level + 1)/128?

[Edit: the internet is telling me, if I understand right, that you can convert bels to decibels by multiplying by 10. If a bel is a unit of 10 dB, then I would think that I could convert units of 0.0235 dB to decibels by multiplying by 0.0235.]

And what do I do different if we're talking about levels for modulators and feedback loop modulators instead of carriers (besides the obvious of how the Web Audio nodes are wired together)? At minimum, there needs to be a place in the formula to put the 0 to 7 feedback parameter.

Now for converting dx7 rates to seconds:

> First, the R parameter in the patch (range 0..99) is converted to a 6 bit value (0..63), by the formula qrate = (rate `*` 41) / 64.

> The rate of decay is then 0.2819 `*` 2<sup>(qrate / 4)</sup> `*` (1 + 0.25 `*` (qrate mod 4)) dB/s. This is a reasaonably good approximation to 0.28 `*` 2<sup>(qrate `*` 0.25)</sup>.

This should give me a dB / s number. Presumably (but you never know with decibels) I can get the seconds from this in the same way as you can get seconds if you know meters traversed and the speed in m/s. From the above, it looks like the dB / s number is available by 0.28 `*` 2 `**` ( (rate `*` 41) / 64 `*` 0.25).

But even if that's so-far-so-good when it comes to decay and release, I don't understand how to compute attack dB / s from that:

> Attack is based on decay, multiplying it by a factor dependent on the current level. In .0235 dB units, this factor is 2 + floor((full scale - current level) / 256). Also, level *immediately* rises to 39.98 dB (1700 steps) above the minimum level, which helps create a crisper attack.

Questions about attack, then:

- Again, how to convert from these 0.0235 dB units to dB?
- Where in the formula would take into account the "immediate" 39.98 dB rise?
- What numbers to plug in for full scale and current level? Current level is level 4, at which we start the attack? I think full scale is supposed to be 0 dB or a gain of 1, but I don't know what number is needed here.